# Resolve DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, SQLERRMC=TBSPACEID=18, TABLEID=11, COLNO=1, DRIVER=4.22.29

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, mapping

I have this big json that I am sending and trying to save the data. I am getting all the data. But when I am doing a db query just to even find the data I keep getting the following error:

```
    2023-06-28 14:02:46.408 ERROR 2359 --- [ntContainer#2-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, SQLERRMC=TBSPACEID=18, TABLEID=11, COLNO=1, DRIVER=4.22.29
    [.2023-06-28 14:02:46,408] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, SQLERRMC=TBSPACEID=18, TABLEID=11, COLNO=1, DRIVER=4.22.29
```

I used below query to find out what it is complaining for:

```
 SELECT C.TABSCHEMA, C.TABNAME, C.COLNAME
 FROM SYSCAT.TABLES AS T,
 SYSCAT.COLUMNS AS C
 WHERE T.TBSPACEID = 18
 AND T.TABLEID = 11
 AND C.COLNO = 1
 AND C.TABSCHEMA = T.TABSCHEMA
 AND C.TABNAME = T.TABNAME
```

And I get the schema name, table name and property name.

The problem is it keep complaining for the mapping:

Here is sample one :

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="PROPERTY")
 @EntityListeners(PropertyListener.class)
 public class Property implements Serializable
 {

    private Document Document;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOC_OBJ_ID", nullable = false)
    @Schema(hidden = true)
    public Document getDocument()
    {
      return document;
    }
    //more elements
   }
```

Here is the document class:

```
     @Entity
     @EntityListeners(DocumentEntityListener.class)
     @Table(name="DOCUMENT")
     @Schema(name = "Document")
     public class Document {

       @Expose
       @SerializedName("property")
       @Schema(name="property")
       private List<Property> propertyList;


       @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy =   "Document",targetEntity = Property.class)
       public List<Property> getPropertyList() {
          return propertyList;
        }
      }
```

Am I missing something in mapping that I need to add.

I have like 20 similar property classes in document. I am getting this error one after another for each one of them if I commented out property.

Is there any mapping guide/reference to make sure the mapping is done right?

What else I can try?

Comment: Is there any way to bump this?